Changing image masks on an image causes flickering
I have a Vue app where on a screen the user can draw on a canvas. I am transferring the base64 data to a mask on an image (like an eraser). I've transferred the data using requestAnimationFrame and setTimeout loops with different intervals. Beneath (in z axis) that image are other elements that are then revealed.
It functions as expected on Chrome (on MacOS and Android). It however does not function well on safari (MacOs & iOS) or chrome on iOS (but that's somewhat expected since it doesn't work on safari as well).
The unexpected behaviour is that it flickers. As if the whole image is masked and then sometimes isn't. Larger mask images cause worse behaviour, but dynamically changing the mask even with smaller masks produces the same unexpected result.
The issue only appears when using the Vue framework, rapidly changing it in vanilla js does not produce the result. I expect the fault lies in performance throttling making it not appear (as frequently) in vanilla js as the load is lower.
I tried reducing the size om the base64 image being transferred, but even when below a resolution standard I can live with, the flickering behaviour is produced.
I have a simple reproduction in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0jnaoqz8/1/
In this code I have used a svg mask instead of a base64 for simplicities sake and because it produces the exact same result.
Is there a way to ensure masks are updated by the Vue framework without reaching performance limits, or is there something else I'm missing here?

In your jsfiddle, there is an error in the console when loading the app, then also when Start generating is clicked. Error: "[Vue warn: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
(found in <Root>)"] Do you have the same error in your 'real' app? Because when running your jsfiddle, the error actually causes the flicker because it is called hundreds of times.

@nom_unique There was indeed a error being logged in the jsfiddle, one I didn't have in my app. I just fixed the error in the fiddle and the behaviour is still present

Thank you! I am not able to give you a solid solution, but since Vue seems to be the problem (on Safari at least), maybe you could try bypassing Vue's reactiviy system and try a "vanilla js" approach in your Vue component. By that I mean not using reactive data like this.svgString = this.generateSvg(). But rather append this.generateSvg() directly to the HTML element's style attribute. Just an idea!
